# Animate Image Rotation of a Button

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm creating a `UIButton` and adding it above a `UITabBar`, in a custom `UITabBarController`.

```
var button = new UIButton(new CGRect(x, y, 50, 50));
button.Layer.BorderWidth = 2;
button.Layer.CornerRadius = button.Frame.Height / 2;
button.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("Name"), UIControlState.Normal);

this.View.AddSubview(button);
this.View.LayoutIfNeeded();
```

When I try to add a rotation transform on the image view, it doesn't rotate around the center and z axis, as I'd expect (and found in every documentation I read).

Instead, it animates somehow different.
It's the same regardless if I add the transform on the `ImageView` or its layer.
This for example is a rotation of 30 degrees (`pi / 180 * 30`) and 10 degrees.

[image][image]

However, when I add a `SublayerTransform` to the button layer, it transforms as expected. The problem with that approach is that it is not animateable with `UIView.Animate` or `CATransaction.Begin`.

`Position`, `AnchorPoint` and everything else is set to default. I tried playing around with these properties too, but to no avail.

As you can see from the images, it's a `+` sign that should animate to become an `x`.

Any hint is very much appreciated.

The 3D transforms I have defined like this:

```
CATransform3D.MakeRotation((float)(Math.PI / 180 * 45), 0, 0, 1)
```

and the normal ones like this:

```
CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation((float)(Math.PI / 180 * 45))
```

Comment: Can you show the exact animating code? I just did a quick test using your code above, and I was able to make a button rotate 45 degrees (what you would want to turn a + to an x) and it worked as expected, both the 3d and 2d versions rotated the button 45 degrees clockwise.

Comment: Oh, re-reading... Oh, rotate the button, not the image. Rotating the button worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to rotate just the button image view for some reason, try this:

```
button.ImageView.Layer.Transform = CATransform3D.MakeRotation((float)(Math.PI / 180 * 45), 0.0001f, 0.0001f, 1);
```

With the x and y values set to 0, it seems that there is still rotation on the x and y axis, though there should not be. With a value of 45 degrees, it rotates the x and y as well so that you are seeing the image edge on (so seems to be rotating x and y by 90 degrees), i.e. it disappears. Putting in a small value for X and y seems to avoid this error. I am going to see if this is exclusive to Xamarin or if it is an iOS thing.

**EDIT:** I just tested this in Obj-C in XCode and got the exact same behavior, so this is not a Xamarin issue but is an issue with iOS and how it is processing transforms for the UIImageView that is in a UIButton. Same issue does not occur with a UIImageView that is *not* in the UIButton.

Comment: I would've never guessed that this is a bug in iOS, great analysis, thanks so much!